# How to redirect wordpress logged users in another page?

Tags: wordpress

I need to redirect all wordpress users that visit a certain page to another page? how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean logged in users there are two ways to go about this :

```
<?php
    //All Users
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        //Do Redirect in your preferred method eg
        header('Location: ' . $fullUrlToGoTo);
    }

    //Users who may be a of certain type eg admins
    if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
        //Do Redirect in your preferred method eg
        header('Location: ' . $fullUrlToGoTo);
    }
?>
```

If it is a fixed page however, and you want **ALL** traffic, not just registered users to go, then a redirect in the .htaccess file, or IIS rewrites would be another solution. Check out https://www.htaccessredirect.net/ which can give you easy redirect solutions to put in your htaccess.